# antlr, how to fix grammar so (varname)? fails parsing if it exists but is wrong

Tags: antlr

I am rewriting this post(same question though, less words).

I rewrote my grammar to just have at the top level this

```
statement: SELECT EOF!;
#removed all other rules and tokens and still not working
SELECT  :   ('S'|'s')('E'|'e')('L'|'l')('E'|'e')('C'|'c')('T'|'t');
```

I then have the following java code(There is no parse method on my Parser like I see on everyone else's posts :( :( )...

```
@Test
public void testGrammar() throws RecognitionException {
    String sql = "select p FROM TABLE p left join p.security s where p.numShares = :shares and s.securityType = :type";

    ANTLRStringStream stream = new ANTLRStringStream(sql);
    NoSqlLexer lexer = new NoSqlLexer(stream);
    CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    NoSqlParser parser = new NoSqlParser(tokenStream);

    try {
        CommonTree tree = (CommonTree) parser.statement().getTree();
        Assert.fail("should fail parsing");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.info("Exception", e);
    }
}
```

I should get an Exception on parsing but I do not :( :(.  This is a very simple grammar with an EOF but it just is not working.  Any ideas why?  Am I calling the wrong parsing statement?

NOTE: I am trying to make a much bigger problem simpler by cutting the problem down to this simple thing which seems not to work.

full (very small) grammar file is here

```
grammar NoSql;


options { 
    output = AST; 
    language = Java;
}

tokens {


}

@header {
package com.alvazan.orm.parser.antlr;
}

@lexer::header {
package com.alvazan.orm.parser.antlr;
}


@rulecatch {
    catch (RecognitionException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

statement: SELECT EOF!;

SELECT  :   ('S'|'s')('E'|'e')('L'|'l')('E'|'e')('C'|'c')('T'|'t');

WS  :
    (   ' '
        |   '\t'
        |   '\r'
        |   '\n'
        )+
        { $channel=HIDDEN; }
        ;  

ESC :
    '\\' ('"'|'\''|'\\')
    ;
```

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should get an Exception on parsing but I do not :( :(. This is a very simple grammar with an EOF but it just is not working.

If you didn't "tell" ANTLR to throw an exception, then ANTLR might not throw an exception/error in case of invalid input. In many cases, ANTLR tries to recover from mismatched/invalid input and tries to continue parsing. You *will* see output being written on the `stderr` in your case, but you might not get an exception.

If you *do* want an exception in your case, see: [ANTLR not throwing errors on invalid input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658753/antlr-not-throwing-errors-on-invalid-input)

Comment: interesting, I thought that was what the rulecatch was for but that must be in another part of the generated code then I guess.  thanks!!!