# How to collect errors during run time given by a parser in Antlr4

Tags: c#-4.0, antlr, antlr3, antlr4

I have upgraded from Antlr 3 to Antlr 4. I was using this code to catch exceptions using this code. But this is not working for Antlr 4.

```
partial class XParser
{
    public override void ReportError(RecognitionException e)
    {
        base.ReportError(e);
        Console.WriteLine("Error in Parser at line " + ":" + e.OffendingToken.Column + e.OffendingToken.Line + e.Message);
    }
}
```

This is the error that appears

```
'Parser.ReportError(Antlr4.Runtime.RecognitionException)': no suitable method found to override
```

In Antlr 4 what is the expected way of accumulating errors that occurs in the input stream. I was unable to find a way to achieve this on the net. Please provide me some guidelines.

EDIT:

I have implemented the XParser as below

```
partial class XParser : IAntlrErrorListener<IToken>
{
    public void SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg, RecognitionException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in parser at line " + ":" + e.OffendingToken.Column + e.OffendingToken.Line + e.Message);
    }
}
```

As you said I can extend this parser class using any of the mentioned classes. But I was unable to register this listener, in the main program I am confused with passing argument as the `listener`. Please help me with the registering.

As I can see these classes has the capability of producing more meaningful error messages don't they?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to implement [`IAntlrErrorListener<IToken>`](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/IAntlrErrorListener%601.cs). If all you want to is report errors like you have above, then you should focus on the `SyntaxError` method. Several base classes are available if you want to extend one.

- [`ConsoleErrorListener`](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/ConsoleErrorListener.cs)
- [`BaseErrorListener`](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/BaseErrorListener.cs)
- [`DiagnosticErrorListener`](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/DiagnosticErrorListener.cs)

The error listener is attached to the parser instance by calling `parser.AddErrorListener(listener)`.

**Edit:** You need to create a new class which implements the error listener interface. You then attach the listener to the parser. The parser itself will not implement the error listener interface.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. I have some confusion and clarification. Thanks for the big help through out the work. Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @290Z28 Thanks that works. Why can't I do the same thing to Lexer. I tried to imitate what I did for the parser by creating another class and implementing from `IAntlrErrorListener<IToken>` . lexer instance has `AddErrorListener` a method.

Comment: confused with the name :)