# Accumulating Lexer errors in ANTLR 4

Tags: c#-4.0, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to accumulate lexer errors when Lexing in run time. I have followed the exact way of achieving this for parser errors as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18486405/892788). But when I try to do this to the Lexer.

```
class Class2 : IAntlrErrorListener<IToken> 
{
    public void SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg, RecognitionException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in lexer at line " + ":" + e.OffendingToken.Column + e.OffendingToken.Line + e.Message);
    }
}
```

and register this listener as below.

```
        Class2 z = new Class2();

        lexer.AddErrorListener(z);
```

But this gives a error which is unexpected.

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CSSParserAntlr.Class2' to 'Antlr4.Runtime.IAntlrErrorListener<int>'
```

and

```
The best overloaded method match for 'Antlr4.Runtime.Recognizer<int,Antlr4.Runtime.Atn.LexerATNSimulator>.AddErrorListener(Antlr4.Runtime.IAntlrErrorListener<int>)' has some invalid arguments
```

Please give me some reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the reason you are getting this exception is because you need to declare Class2 as follows:

```
class Class2 : IAntlrErrorListener<int>
```

in order to match the class signature of Lexer defined as follows:

```
public abstract class Lexer : Recognizer<int, LexerATNSimulator>, ITokenSource
```

The method signature for AddErrorListener is defined in Recognizer to match the Symbol type from the class definition as follows:

```
public abstract class Recognizer<Symbol, ATNInterpreter> : IRecognizer
```

This means that Lexer specifies "int" as the "Symbol" when extending Recognizer, and so the AddErrorListener method requires an IAntlrErrorListener of type int.

Now, the **real answer** to your question: don't write an error listener for a lexer. Errors in the lexing are the fault of the lex grammar, not of the user input. Error listeners are useful for handling bad user input in a Parser. Lexer grammars should be tested for coverage during development - i.e., all possible input will match some token. If you encounter a lex error during development, the default error listener will do just fine.

For more information, see the answer here: [ANTLR4 Lexer error reporting (length of offending characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782388/antlr4-lexer-error-reporting-length-of-offending-characters)