# Why Antrl4 ErrorListener is not firing SyntaxError method?

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have a grammar on Antlr4.
I am trying to implement a custom error listeners (to grab all syntax errors to a UI control).

I have followed the guidelines to implement:

```
class ReaderErrorListener : IAntlrErrorListener<IToken>
    {
        public void SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg, RecognitionException e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Invalid Expressions: line {0}:{1} -  {2}", line, charPositionInLine, msg);
        }
    }
```

And registered the listener against my parser:

```
string str = "writqwee(path.subnode.field, 0xa5)";
var lexer = new ReaderLexer(new AntlrInputStream(str));
var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new ReaderParser(tokens);
parser.RemoveErrorListeners();
parser.AddErrorListener(new ReaderErrorListener());
var tree = parser.root();
```

A valid input to my parser is `write(path.subnode.field, 0xa5)`
so the above input is expected to be a syntax error.

The `tree` variable is empty (as expected), but `SyntaxError` method never gets called.

In my grammar the "write" word is identified as a lexer rule...

```
TWO_ARG_KEYWORD :   
        'write'
    ;
```

I've reviewed and followed [How to collect errors during run time given by a parser in Antlr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484869/how-to-collect-errors-during-run-time-given-by-a-parser-in-antlr4) but with no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As a random guess, did you maybe not anchor your `root` rule to `EOF` in your grammar? That's a common reason for getting empty results wihtout syntax errors.

Comment: Since `writeqwee` does not match `write`, no `TWO_ARG_KEYWORD` token will be issued. Instead the input string is (apparently) validly matched elsewhere, resulting in no error exception.  Dump the token stream to see how the string is actually being lexed/recognized.