# ANTLR4 Not reporting errors

Tags: error-handling, antlr4

I created a grammar to represent an existing language.  When running through the thousands of files that already exist there are a handful that are causing me a headache.  They include some syntax that doesn't make any sense and should be throwing an error but instead antlr4 seems to trash half of the code and not report an error at all.  There are < in places that are not expected and even antlr labs seems to recognize them as unidentified but does not report them as an error.  Is there some kind of setting for making the parser report unknown parts of the language?  Most of the time it reports errors successfully but i keep running into these situations were it doesn't and just discards part of the code entirely.

Trying to parse a code file with a snytax error and was just getting some partial grammar tree back with no errors.

Comment: Sounds like the classic problem of not having an `EOF` at the end of the top level parser rule (to force consideration of the entire input). Cannot tell for sure without seeing the full grammar.

Comment: It heavily depends on the grammar file and the glue code you use, as ANTLR by default (in older versions or 4.0) attempts to recover from simple errors (but that doesn't seem to be what you wanted). You'd better grab a reference book to go through all necessary details before working on a grammar, or you miss such concepts and start to have questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANTLR not throwing errors on invalid input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658753/antlr-not-throwing-errors-on-invalid-input)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
String source = "input to parse";

Lexer lexer = new YourLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
Parser parser = new YourParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

parser.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());

// TODO: invoke the entry point of your parser here
```

which will cause any error during parsing to throw an exception: ANTLR will not try to recover from it.